# Power BI Custom Visuals Exporting to PDF

Tags: pdf, export, powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a number of custom visuals, wrote due to the fact that there wasn't any other visual that met my requirement (obviously) and they work fine. But, when I go to export to PDF, the custom visuals do not show.

Having looked at the Power BI documentation, there is talk of rendering events in order to export to PDF or PowerPoint, but no working examples.

Does anyone have a working example of how a custom visual can export to PDF?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-pdf#limitations-and-considerations), custom visuals in PDF export is supported only if they are certified:

> Custom visuals that have been certified are supported. For more information on certified custom visuals, including how to get a custom visual certified, see [Get a custom visual certified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/power-bi-custom-visuals-certified). Custom visuals that haven't been certified aren't supported. In the PDF, they display with an error message.

If you follow the link [Get a custom visual certified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/power-bi-custom-visuals-certified), you will find a long list of certification requirements. If you comply with them, you should [submit your visuals for certification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/power-bi-custom-visuals-certified#process-for-submitting-a-custom-visual-for-certification), by sending an e-mail (!!!) to Power BI Power BI visuals Support team (pbicvsupport@microsoft.com) with a link to GitHub repository, where your visuals are hosted.

Comment: I'll look to see if I can get one of them into the marketplace, will need a little work since they are geared towards company use only.